# How to show the product "add to cart" button on a product kit?

Tags: ubercart

I would like to add a "add to cart" button on a product kit, for each product in the product kit. How may I achieve that? I have been searching for a while now. Ubercart 3.

This would be similar to iTunes when viewing an album, the user may buy a single song of the album. Currently with product kit, the user has to click the product link to get to the song then be able to buy it.

Answer (score -1):

Drupal has a number of modules that make "add to cart" and other similar features of Drupal commerce work, by simply enabling those modules.Check out the following links:

1. [Commerce Line Item Cart Form](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_line_item_cart_form)
2. This link may also help- [Cart Modules](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/extensions/module/cart)

Comment: Drupal Commerce != Ubercart...

Comment: @Rakhi, I'm using Ubercart 3 not Drupal Commerce.